Can the support of a Borel probability measure has measure between 0 and 1?
On Wikipedia, the support of a Borel measure $\mu$ on a topological space $X$ is determined by:
$$\operatorname{supp}\mu=\lbrace x\in X:\mu(U)>0,\forall U \text{ open, containing } x\rbrace.$$
The examples therein present some Borel probability measures that have supports of measure either $0$ or $1$.
My question: Is there a Borel probability measure $\mu$ with support of measure between 0 and 1, i.e $\mu(\operatorname{supp}\mu)\in(0,1)?$

Just take half the Dieudonné measure in Wikipedia plus half a Dirac measure at some point, no?
